# Why is 2^53 === 2^53+1 true in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I can not understand that 2^53 === 2^53+1 is true in JavaScript.

```js
let test = 2 ** 53 === 2 ** 53 + 1;
console.log(test); // true
```

THANKS.

Comment: Because both are greater than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`

Comment: https://groups.google.com/g/twitter-development-talk/c/ahbvo3VTIYI

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER

Comment: Thanks. I understand it better!